# Difference between VARCHAR2 and LONG datatype on Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, types

We use the VARCHAR2 datatype to store variable-length character data.The VARCHAR2 datatype takes a required parameter that specifies a maximum size up to 32767 bytes.

We use the LONG datatype to store variable-length character strings. The LONG datatype is like the VARCHAR2 datatype, except that the maximum size of a LONG value is 32760 bytes.

Is there any other difference except from the Maximum size?

Comment: `Long` is depricated and is only for backward compatibility. never use it

Answer (score 5):

Shortly, forget that LONG exists. It is here for backward compatibility. If you have to store *a lot of text* into a column, use **CLOB** datatype.

More info here: [LONG datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1831).

Comment: CLOB is there , but we can use VARCHAR2 as well. so what is the difference between VARCHAR2 and CLOB? I believe the difference of size (8 to 128 terabytes for CLOB).

Comment: `Clob` is the abbreviation for Character Large Object
So the data type is to save large texts. But if you get along with 32767 characters, you do not need to use Clob. Working with Clob is also slower than with Varchar2

Answer (score -3):

The VARCHAR2 datatype takes a required parameter that specifies a maximum size up to 32767 bytes.Long datatype is same like as varchar2 except the maximum size of long value is 32760 bytes.